# Is it possible to read different queries in a .gql file with karate framework?

Tags: graphql, karate

```html
query ExampleQuery1  {
    campaignArticles(
        page:0
        size: 10
        categoryId:"3aac6513-fb0d-4ed1-8fc3-f8d9aec08638")
    {
        content {
            id
            ... on CampaignArticle {
                displayPlace
                title
                shortDescription
                longDescription
                publishEndDate
                endDateCountdown
                campaignEndDateVisible
                personal
                personalMedia{
                    id
                    type
                    url
                    videoPreviewImage
                }
                listViewMedia {
                    id
                    type
                    url
                    videoPreviewImage
                }
                scenarios {
                    id
                    scenarioId
                    scenarioName
                }
                externalMembershipPartner
                optin {
                    id
                    formExist
                    limitExceeded
                    buttonText
                    buttonDisabledText
                }
                favorite
                brand {
                    id
                    name
                    logo{
                        id
                        type
                        url
                        videoPreviewImage
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        page {
            number
            size
            totalElements
            totalPages
        }
    }
}

query ExampleQuery1  {
    campaignCategories(page: 0, size: 10) {
        content {
            ... on CampaignCategory {
                name
                version
                id
            }
        }
    }
}

query ExampleQuery2  {
    campaignCategories(page: 0, size: 10) {
        content {
            ... on CampaignCategory {
                name
                version
                id
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to read different queries in a .gql file. I found an example but it didn't work
"Given request read('requestGraphQL.gql', 'ExampleQuery1')" using read method like this giving this error "org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: execute on com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine$$Lambda$89 failed due to: Arity error - expected: 1 actual: 2

- .:program(Unnamed:1)"

I am sharing my .gql file and scenario steps. If it's possible to read queries in a file please help me with that. Added 3 screenshots to explain my code.

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is my .gql file, and I want to read these queries by name. I aim to prevent to the use of multiple files for every query

```
@55547
```

Scenario: LimitTanimiListesiAlma

```
Given def query = read('requestGraphQL.gql')
And request { query: '#(query)' }
And header app-version = "3.0.0"
And header platform = "app-store"
And header Accept = "*/*"
When method post
Then status 200
Then print response
```

Comment: Please post the code as a text, not an image.

Comment: i added my gql file and scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to solve my problem. I am using .js file intead of .gql file, returning request with javascript function.

```js
function(){
  return {
    graphqlFunction: function()
    {
    const MY_GRAPHQL_QUERY = `query ($categoryId: UUID!){
                                  campaignArticles(
                                      page:0
                                      size: 10
                                      categoryId: $categoryId )
                                  {
                                      content {
                                          id
                                          ... on CampaignArticle {
                                              displayPlace
                                              title
                                              shortDescription
                                              longDescription
                                              publishEndDate
                                              endDateCountdown
                                              campaignEndDateVisible
                                              personal
                                              personalMedia{
                                                  id
                                                  type
                                                  url
                                                  videoPreviewImage
                                              }
                                              listViewMedia {
                                                  id
                                                  type
                                                  url
                                                  videoPreviewImage
                                              }
                                              scenarios {
                                                  id
                                                  scenarioId
                                                  scenarioName
                                              }
                                              externalMembershipPartner
                                              optin {
                                                  id
                                                  formExist
                                                  limitExceeded
                                                  buttonText
                                                  buttonDisabledText
                                              }
                                              favorite
                                              brand {
                                                  id
                                                  name
                                                  logo{
                                                      id
                                                      type
                                                      url
                                                      videoPreviewImage
                                                  }
                                              }
                                          }
                                      }
                                      page {
                                          number
                                          size
                                          totalElements
                                          totalPages
                                      }
                                  }
                              }`
        return MY_GRAPHQL_QUERY;
    }
  }
}
```

@55547
Scenario: LimitTanimiListesiAlma

```
Given def query = jsFile.graphqlFunction()
And def variables = { categoryId: '3aac6513-fb0d-4ed1-8fc3-f8d9aec08638' }
And request { query: '#(query)', variables: '#(variables)' }
And header app-version = "3.0.0"
And header platform = "app-store"
And header Accept = "*/*"
When method post
Then status 200
Then print response
```

Comment: This is a fine solution to your problem, but now the title of the Question is misleading.

Comment: What should i do, change the title ? Can u help me?

Comment: I changed the title maybe it's correct now, If it's not please tell me what should i do.

Answer (score 1):

The `read()` function takes only one argument.

```
* request read('requestGraphQL.gql')
```

The above should be good enough.

Comment: This usage allows me to read only one query for a .gql file. Should I use a different file for every query or there is a way to read the specific query in a file?

Comment: @HakanAras yes, I thought a single file for each query is pretty standard and that's what karate supports and arguably more readable and maintainable. if you really want you could write a Java helper to load a custom format.

Comment: Thank you so much for help, I recommending everyone to use karate for api automation. The Best framework <3